# JNI C++ UnsatisfiedLinkError When Calling Method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have been trying to create a simple JNI Test with C++. For Java I am using Eclipse, and for C++ I am using Visual Studio 2013. I followed the directions on other pages on StackOverFlow but nothing really seems to work. The error occurs when I try calling the native method in java listed in C++.

Thanks for your time.

## Header.h

```
#include <jni.h>;
using namespace std;
#ifndef Header
#define Header
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_base_Main_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
#endif
```

## Edited Header.h (solution which worked)

```
#include <jni.h>;
using namespace std;

#ifndef Header
#define Header

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_base_Main_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
}
#endif
```

## JNIHelloWorld.cpp

```
#include "Header.h";

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_base_Main_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    printf("This is a JNI tester\n");
    //return;
}
```

## JavaCode

```
package base;
public class Main {
    static {System.loadLibrary("JNIHelloWorld");}
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main m = new Main();
        m.print();
    }
    public native void print();
}
```

## Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: base.Main.print()V
    at base.Main.print(Native Method)
    at base.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try #extern "c" { } around the JNI code.

Verify by looking at the exports of your DLL to see that the C++ name mangling did not get involved.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks :) *tries to upvote your answer but sees that a rep of 15 is needed ): *

Comment: I did it instead!